# How to remove parts of a file name

Tags: linux, rename

Ive got multiple mp3 files named like so:

artist - year - album - track - title.mp3

about half of them, due to a "rename from tag" error are named like this:

artist - year - album - track - title - - .mp3

how do I make the last example look like the first in ubuntu.  Due to errors now in the tags, I am unable to use the tag program to rename the files with out messing up the currently correct file names, unless I spent a lot of time looking for and selecting for the mis-named files.

If I could move the mis-named files to another directory, I would be able to use the tag program to fix the file names, but how do I move ONLY the mis-named files?

thanks

Comment: Place [part of] output of `ls -1 | cat -t`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the utility `rename`, you can do something along the lines of:

```
rename -e 's/ - - //' *.mp3
```

To be safe, before you run the above, run it with the `-n` flag, for a dry run. It won't change any files, but will show you what it would change, like so:

```
$ rename -n -e 's/ - - //' *.mp3
rename(artist - year - album - track - title - - .mp3, artist - year - album - track - title.mp3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `mv $(ls -1 | grep -- '- -') /path/to/dir_to_for_retagging/`. Better do `echo mv ...` first to see what will it do.

Comment: mv $(ls -1 | grep -- '- -') /path/to/dir_to_for_retagging/

results in: 

mv: missing destination file operand after..destination directory

Answer (score 0):

```
mv *--.mp3 /path/to/dir
```

should work fine.

Comment: May be `mv *' - -.mp3' /path/to/dir/`? There are space characters.

Comment: $ mv *' - - .mp3 ~/Desktop/u/
mv: cannot stat `-': No such file or directory
for both dashes

Comment: mv *--.mp3 /path/to/dir mv: cannot stat `*--.mp3': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
for i in $(ls *--.mp3); do mv $i `echo $i | sed s/--// ; done
```

(untested). This'll remove all -- from the file names.